The second signature invalidates the initial signature - iText 8.0.3
When adding another signature or upgrading the initial signature from PAdES B-T to PAdES B-LT:
byte[] addLTV(byte[] in)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException, java.io.IOException {
        IOcspClient ocsp = new OcspClientBouncyCastle(new com.itextpdf.signatures.OCSPVerifier(null, null));
        ICrlClient crl = new CrlClientOnline();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(in));
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer, new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
        LtvVerification v = new LtvVerification(pdfDoc);
        SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDoc);
        List<String> names   = signatureUtil.getSignatureNames();
        String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);
        PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = signatureUtil.readSignatureData(sigName);
        if (pkcs7.isTsp()) {
            v.addVerification(sigName, ocsp, crl, LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                              LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL, LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
        } else {
            for (String name : names) {
                v.addVerification(name, ocsp, crl, LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                                  LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL, LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.YES);
            }
        }
        v.merge();
        pdfDoc.close();
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

the initial signature becomes invalid with an error "the document has been altered or corrupted since the Signature was applied.
Upon inspection, I found that the initial signature becomes invalid as soon as it's read by PdfDocument or PdfSigner.
String srcFileName = "./BT.pdf";
        String outFileName = "./B-LT01.pdf";
        PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(srcFileName), new PdfWriter(outFileName), new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
        document.close();

The code works fine with other PDF files. How can I resolve this issue?
my pdf file

As already hinted at by @KJ in a comment to the question, the issue here is caused by an error in the initial revision of the document, the revision even before the first signature. When validating signatures in a PDF with changes applied after that signature, Adobe Acrobat tries to check whether those changes are allowed or disallowed; this check is very sensitive, and in case of certain errors in the initial document revision it reports an invalid signature (instead of a broken initial document revision which would be the correct thing to report).
This already has been discussed elsewhere, e.g. here on stack overflow in this answer or on the Adobe Community forum in this answer.
Just like in the case of the referred-to stack overflow question & answer, that original revision has been produced by an Aspose product (according to the document metadata by "Aspose.PDF for .NET 24.5.1"), so apparently Aspose have not yet had the time to fix the bug in their software producing these issues. That bug has been known for at least 8 years now; maybe they have grown fond of it and don't want to give it up anymore.
In detail
The issue that most likely makes Acrobat report the broken signature here is the invalid cross reference table of the first document revision. It consists of multiple subsections:
xref
0 2573
0000000000 65535 f
0000000023 00000 n
...
0000258439 00000 n
0000259189 00000 n
2574 19
0000321853 00000 n
0000322470 00000 n
...
0000347153 00000 n
0000347296 00000 n
2616 3
0000348429 00000 n
0000348493 00000 n
0000433193 00000 n

This is forbidden for an initial revision:

For a PDF file that has never been incrementally updated, the cross-reference section shall contain only one subsection, whose object numbering begins at 0.

(ISO 32000-2 section 7.5.4)
As already mentioned by @KJ, there also are other errors (or at least very questionable structures) in that revision.

Looking more closely at the other errors in that first revision, it seems unlikely that all of them have been caused by Aspose.PDF. Additionally considering that there are conflicting producer information ("Aspose.PDF for .NET 24.5.1" according to the Info dictionary, "Microsoft® Word for Microsoft 365" according to the XMP metadata), multiple programs were involved in generating that first revision, and it is not clear whom to blame for which errors.
